# Grease Pencil with Pressure makes lines disappear

Tags: grease-pencil

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JioJS.jpg

Hi

I wanna draw with Grease pencil, but when I turn on the Radius Pressure, the lines disappear immediately.

and if I turn on the Strength Pressure, it draws nothing.

Not only the Wacom pen but also Mouse does too.

But in a new project file, it works correctly.

(I have already tried to Append the objects to new project, then it has the same issue.)

​

I set Tablet API - Wintab.

Blender version is 2.83

​

Anybody know about this issue?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You have pressure disabled for Strength pressure (the pen icon), and a very small radius for the line stroke.

Use larger values.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! :) I have tried, but it has still same problem. but I found out, when I turn on the Stroke-Rendomize-Pressure and Radius Pressure, it draws thin. (not anymore disappeard)